# Windows netstat reports an "amnesia:2554" connection: what the hell is "vcnet-link-v10"?

Tags: windows, networking, connection, netstat

Running `netstat` in Windows reports this line:

```
TCP    192.168.1.161:59065    amnesia:2554           TIME_WAIT
```

`192.168.1.161` it's me, but we have no “amnesia” host on the network.

Looking for [info about port `2554` I found](https://www.grc.com/port_2554.htm) that it is related to `vcnet-link-v10`. Still, I found no info whatsoever about it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! amnesia:2554 is Google Chrome incognito. I don't now why netstat doesn't identify it right away.

Answer (score 0):

A port number in and of itself doesn’t mean that a known service that uses that port is actually using it. If the thing worries you, it’s best to find out what actual program is using the port.

**Windows:**

```
netstat -b -a
```

**Linux:**

```
netstat --programs
```

Will show the PiD and name of the program with every connection. You can then decide if further action is needed.